# AVFoundation converting from HEVC to H264 video

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetwriter, avassetexportsession, hevc

I am converting HEVC video to H264 video using AVFoundation APIs. However I have two problems:

1. How do I detect the video encoder used in the input file using AVFoundation?
2. How do I calculate the bitrate of the output H264 file that matches the quality of input HEVC file? Need to pass this bitrate to AVAssetWriter compression settings dictionary.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to let QuickTime play hevc video(recorded by IP Camera) normally, but it doesn't work, could you give some advices? Thanks!